# Can not create file on Android 2.2, works on Android 4.x

Tags: android

I am using Android 2.2 and i want to create new file

```
//external storage directory path
extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();    
//creating a new folder
File mkTarDir=new File(extStorageDirectory + NewFolder);
mkTarDir.mkdir();
//path to save a image              
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory + NewFolder ,"myimage"+
        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".PNG");
```

folder is created but no file in it. Also no error.

I also have a permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>
```

It si working on android 4 but not on 2.2. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`extStorageDirectory  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`